Replace null in last row of the column to text in lead function
Does someone know how to replace null in last row of the column to text in lead function for example
I'm using
select cust_id, ticketid, 
    lead(ticketid,1, no more tickets) over (order by ticket_id) as nextticketid,
    date as bookingdate
from booking_tickets
where day >= date '2024-04-01'
order by ticketid ASC

Columns cust_id, ticketid, nextticketid bookingdate from table booking_tickets
I want here to get result of last row to show end of tickets instead of null or being empty but every time I get mismatch input.
I want the output to be like
Cust_id.  Ticketid.   Nextticketid. Bookingdate
1.          234.         235.        1 apr2024
2.          235.         236.        2 apr2024
3.          236.   No more tickets

But I'm getting error:

Mismatched input 'more'. Expecting: '%', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '->', '.', '/', 'AND', 'AT', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'OVER', '[', '||', , 


The  tag is for general ISO/ANSI SQL. You should also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Now we don't know what RDBMS you are actually using though. Tag the product you are using still.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And show us a complete query.

LAST_VALUE with IGNORE NULLS?

Sorry, but the  tag doesn't tell us which SQL functionality that can be used,

Im really sorry but Im new here and its my first question so i cant get ur actual point, could u please claift the exact details you need?

Actually im using redash on my browser i dont have any server or anything else installed

Connected to ms sql server and oracle

I will edit with the new look

Let it be sql server and i edited the look query after applying the needed text

Edited all, could u please take a look?

Added the full error msg

Obviously for a given dataset a given column must contain only a single data type, so you can't combine numbers and strings in the same column, that's something your presentation later should handle

You should use a string, something like: LEAD(cast(ticket_id as nvarchar(100)), 1, 'Out of tickets') over(...)

This is my query

select cust_id, ticketid, lead(ticketid,1, no more tickets) over (order by ticket_id) as nextticketid , date as bookingdate from booking_tickets
where day >= date '2024-04-01'
order by ticketid ASC

You seem to be mixing query logic with presentation concerns. How the output is rendered is not the job of SQL. With the query you should focus on getting the data, not presentation concerns like printing "No more tickets". Have your query produce NULL when there is no data, and have the programming environment that gets the query results deal with a nice readable rendering.

Its not presentation concerns i just need to add no more ticket as result to be shown on the empty last row

That is a presentation concern.

I have already answered your question, you can't combine numbers and stings in the same column at query level (and yes it is a presentation issue - cos it's not a data issue - null is correct at a data level)

@dalek is there another way or sub query that can be done to add this text? To the last row, i tried with case when / with as sub queries but didnt work

Hanz, use your programming environment for dealing with presentation (the "to be shown" part).

Oh and you need to use single quotes around a string - that's what's causing the current error.

The only way you can do it is as siggermannen already showed you, convert the numbers to strings ... But that is a bad idea

It worked thanks a ton siggemannen, many thanks for ur help also @dale K

With the following table and dataset:
CREATE TABLE booking_tickets
(Cust_id INT,  Ticketid INT, Bookingdate DATE);

INSERT INTO booking_tickets VALUES
(1, 234, '2024-04-01'),
(2, 235, '2024-04-02'),
(3, 236, '2024-04-03');

One query could be :
SELECT Cust_id, Ticketid, 
       COALESCE(
          CAST(
             LEAD(Ticketid, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Ticketid)
             AS VARCHAR(32)), 
          'no more tickets') AS nextticketid,
       Bookingdate 
FROM   booking_tickets
WHERE  Bookingdate >= '2024-04-01'
ORDER  BY Ticketid ASC;

The result is :
Cust_id     Ticketid    nextticketid                     Bookingdate
----------- ----------- -------------------------------- -----------
1           234         235                              2024-04-01
2           235         236                              2024-04-02
3           236         no more tickets                  2024-04-03

If you want the last booking date to be NULL, you can use a CASE expression to do it.
